# Total .npz file has much bigger size than individual elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, save, byte

I've been using numpy's `savez` function to save an aggregate of numpy arrays, and something weird has been happening. I created the dict with all the arrays I wanted to save, and then printed the `nbytes` of each individual element of it by using:

```py
for key, item in data.items():

        print(f'{key:10s}: {str(item.dtype):20s}:{str(item.shape):20s} -- {item.nbytes:0.2f}B = {item.nbytes/10e6:0.2f}MB;')
```

and my output was:

```
values    : float64             :(34542, 2, 150, 1)   -- 82900800.00B = 8.29MB;
names     : <U4                 :(2,)                 -- 32.00B = 0.00MB;
labels    : int32               :(34571,)             -- 138284.00B = 0.01MB;
timestamp : timedelta64[ns]     :(34571,)             -- 276568.00B = 0.03MB;
valid     : uint8               :(34571,)             -- 34571.00B = 0.00MB;
```

which ads up to around 8.3MB of total data. However, when I save this aggregate using:

```py
np.savez(outfile, **data)
```

the resulting `.npz` is almost **10 times** bigger, with 81MB! For reference, when I use `savez_compressed` instead, the file ends up with a much more sensible 3.3MB. So, what is the cause for this huge discrepancy when using `savez`?

Comment: Use `item.nbytes/1e6` to get the correct MB.

Comment: Well that was a silly mistake. Thanks.